# Harmonic series removing all terms with a $0$ in the denominator

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I'd like to prove that the harmonic series, when all the values containing a "0" in the denominator are removed, is convergent. I'm afraid I honestly do not know where to start so any help whatsover would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Courtesy of [SMBC comics](https://smbc-comics.com/index.php?id=3777):

[image]

In the interval between $10^n$ and $10^{n+1}-1$ (positive integer numbers with $n+1$ digits) we have exactly $9^{n+1}$ numbers with no zero in their decimal representation. If we denote as $E$ the set of positive integers with such a property, we have

$$ \sum_{n\in E}\frac{1}{n} = \sum_{k\geq 0}\sum_{n\in E\cap[10^{k},10^{k+1}-1]}\frac{1}{n}\leq \sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{9^{k+1}}{10^k}=90. $$
[There are interesting tricks](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2491559/a-numerical-curiosity-about-the-kempner-series) for an accurate numerical evaluation of the LHS.

It is also true that if we denote as $G$ the set of positive integers such that $666$ is not a substring of their decimal representation, $\sum_{n\in G}\frac{1}{n}$ still is convergent.

Comment: There are quite a few tricks. The original Kempner series has a value of $22.9206766192641503481636570943759319149447624369984815685419983565721563381899111294456260374482$, for instance (cf. [here](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=11&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjxjY_95f3YAhVIb1AKHWxwCyUQFghJMAo&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.e-periodica.ch%2Fcntmng%3Fpid%3Dedm-001%3A1993%3A48%3A%3A200&usg=AOvVaw1MuVmae-n6gIW_K9uSAUS0), though that's in German).

Answer (score 3):

We have a sequence of terms $\frac 1n$  and we will be excluding those terms with a $0$ in the denominator.

There are 9 terms where $n\le 10$

Each term is less than 1.

The sum of these terms is less than  $9$  (It is actually less than 3, but we are just looking for an upper bound.)

There are 81 terms where $10<n\le 100$

Each term is less than $\frac {1}{10}$

The sum of these terms is less than $\frac {9^2}{10}$

There are $9^3$ terms where $100<n\le 1000$

The sum of these terms is less than $\frac {9^3}{10^2}$ etc.

There is a convergent geometric series as an upper bound for your series.